# Log Tail Viewer Control for .Net 3.5

Tags: .net

Currently I am working on Test Automation in which we are trying to test our server by randomizing server calls through 1...n number of users. for the purpose we are logging activities, errors and informations in a log file using Log4Net tool.

Now i need to know if there is any control (preferablly free control) that works like bairtail (http://baremetalsoft.com/baretail/) software or any other log tail viewers. i know there are techniques we can build this for ourself but we are just looking for already built and tested component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/logviewer.aspx)'s a CodeProject article describing a log viewer built with WPF (source is available). Maybe you can build upon that?

And [here](http://log2console.codeplex.com/) is another C# log viewer for log4net on Codeplex.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [xpolog](http://www.xpolog.com). It does what you need.