# looking for a free(non commercial) log viewer with filtering and searching functions for database logs?

Tags: .net, log4net, log4view

I am using log4net to log to a database, and I was requested to find a tool to filter and search through the logs in the database. I dealt with log file viewers before and i found LogExpert which is log file viewer completely free and it provides many functionalities such as search, filter and highlight. So i am looking for something like this but for database logs.

**Edited**

I have found a couple of tools. log4view and logview4net. logview4net is quite simple it only shows but it doesnt allow searchig, filtering and grouping. But log4view is exactly what i need. this tool is great as it allows to view database logs as well as text files. Its Great tool. I am just learning how to use and its easy to use and am loving it.

Comment: Hi, this question might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679512/log-tail-viewer-control-for-net-3-5/1679535#1679535

Comment: @andyp Thanks i will check out the log2console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chainsaw V2 can give you the ability to filter and search events from a database if you configure it with a CustomSQLDBReceiver.

Chainsaw V2 can be downloaded from here: 
http://logging.apache.org/chainsaw/

Info on the receiver is here (or Chainsaw's help menu):
http://logging.apache.org/log4j/companions/receivers/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/db/CustomSQLDBReceiver.html

There's a new version of Chainsaw with a lot of additional features - not yet released, but a pre-release can be downloaded from here:
http://people.apache.org/~sdeboy/

Answer (score -1):

google: http://sourceforge.net/projects/cglogviewer/

Comment: i checked this tool it seems a bit too simple. Any other suggestions?